# How to find all tar files in various sub-folders, then extract them in the same folder they were found?

Tags: linux, bash, automation, centos, tar

I have lots of sub-folders, with only some containing a tar file. i.e.:

```
folder1/
folder2/this-is-a.tar
folder3/
folder4/this-is-another.tar
```

I can find which dirs have the tar by simply doing `ls */*.tar`.

What I want to achieve is somehow find all .tar files, then extract them in the same directory they are found, then delete the .tars.

I've tried `ls */*.tar | xargs -n1 tar xvf` but that extracts the tars in in the directory I'm in, not the directory the tars were found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in */*.tar ; do pushd `dirname $i` ; tar xf `basename $i` && rm `basename $i` ; popd ; done
```

Edit: this is probably a better way:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.tar" -print0 -execdir tar xf {} \; -delete
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in */*.tar; do
    (cd `dirname $file`; tar xvf `basename $file`)
    unlink $file
done
```